# How to call a href by onclick event of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, onclick

I have the following `a href` I use to open jquery dialogs, which works fine. Basically, the openDialog class has attached the jquery dialog code:

```
 <a class='openDialog' data-dialog-id='myEditDlg' data-dialog-autosize='false' data-dialog-alt='580' data-dialog-larg='740' data-dialog-title='test dialog' href='/mycontroller/EditDlg/myid'></a>
```

**Now, I'd like to call it by the `onclick` event of a button.**
Basically, I'd like to have the same behaviour of the clicked `<a class='openDialog' href` when I click a button. How can I do it?**

Comment: Where do you assign the handler that opens the dialog (i.e. JavaScript code)? You probably need to alter the selector to include certain buttons.

Comment: In JQuery, binding to an element's onclick event is as simple as $('.selector').click(function() { ... }).
Having said that, I'm not sure what your question is asking...

Comment: Thank you all. Sorry, phearps the question is not well formulated...basically, I'd like to have the same behaviour of the <a class='openDialog' href when I click a button. How can I do it?

Comment: But what piece of JavaScript code is responsible for opening the dialog? You can probably alter that such that a button does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you @pimvdb. In fact I need to know how to write the code to reproduce the a href click event... but I have no idea how I can do it.

Comment: What dialog plug-in are you using? There are tons of them.

Comment: Please drop the tags in titles, and signatures in posts. And don't write answers in questions.

Answer (score 6):

If I get you question right then may be jQuery [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)(?) is what you are looking for.
Example:

```
<button id="bt">Click</button>
<a href="example.com" id="ex">Triggerable link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#bt').click(function() {
       $('#ex').click();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Basically, I'd like to have the same behaviour of the <a class='openDialog' href when I click a button. Do you think it can be done with the .trigger? Could you write an example, please? THX

Comment: What I understand is: You want a `button` which when clicked behaves as if your `a` tag is clicked. In that case the above code should work.

Comment: Thank you @check123! Now I put code it is more clear to me. Pheraps it could work. So - pls tell me if it is wrong - I should put a hidden a href for each button I have and then bind the trigger, right?
So, when I click on the button, the hidden a hrefs are opened, right?

Comment: You can do that. Or better why not style the 'a' tag to look like a button. Then you can rid yourself of all that useless burden. http://www.google.com/search?q=style+anchor+tags+as+button

Comment: Thanks again @check123. I am going to do some test with your precious suggestions and I'll let you know!

Comment: Thank you very much! Your last solution is exactly what I needed! I am using styled anchors and it works fine! THX!

Comment: Sorry check123, I removed solution because the main answer is not exactly the real solution to the problem. I wrote inside the question the solution of style the anchors as you suggested, but it did not respect forum rules, so it has been removed. If you could edit your answer, putting your other suggestions too, I think it could be understood by others who have my same problem. Then I'll mark again your as the answer. THX

Comment: Never mind all these little things. That it was of help to you is important rest all is secondary.

Answer (score 5):

You can emulate the click by

```
 $('#link').click();//No arguments inside the call.
```

This will emulate the click event on the link. It is the same as clicking on the link. This ofcourse won't change the location if you have an event handler that stops the default behavior of the link
If you want to redirect to the href attribute you can use:

```
 location.href=$('#link').attr('href');
```

So if you want to call this on click of a button.

```
$('#button').click(function(){$('#link').click();
   location.href=$('#link').attr('href');//In case the page doesn't change although you want it to
}
```

Comment: Thank you! First I am going to follow code123 suggestion. I could have several buttons and hrefs, so I think that it could be convenient, please tell me if I wrong. I am just a beginner. Thank you very much!
I'll let you know.

Comment: they're the same, actually. If you want the user to follow the link to another page, use location.href method. If you want to emulate a click, you can use either of our methods. The first line in my code does basically the same as code123's method.

Comment: THX for your help. In my case I just need to open a jquery dialog and remain on the same page. For this reason I prefer to mantain the `<a>`, adding the `openDialog` class to it and styling like a button. I have a `live` `click` binding on the openDialog class, which opens a jquery dialog. Thank you very much!

Comment: u cud just use a button tag instead of a

Comment: THX. I need to have a button behaviour, but a custom style. For example, I do not need button border, neither a 3D aspect of a button. Anyway now it works as I needed. THX