# In reactJS, how to invoke link click via button press?

Tags: reactjs

I have a button.  When the users presses it, I want the outcome ot be the same as if the user had pressed a specific link.

Put another way, I want to represent a link as a button.

I can see from this that it is possible using Jquery:
[How to call a href by onclick event of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9444243/627492)

What is the "correct" way to do this in ReactJS?

Comment: You can possibly use style anchor (<a>) tags and have a link in form of href. No need of ReactJS to handle it.

Comment: Just style link as a button using CSS. Or use Bootstrap

Answer (score 47):

Like this:

```
<button
    type="button"
    onClick={(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location.href='http://google.com';
      }}
> Click here</button>
```

Comment: Is adding `e.preventDefault()` necessary? It works fine without it as well. Could you please mention the purpose?

Comment: Can we still use this method and target a new tab?

Answer (score 21):

Use [React-Router Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md),instead of **Anchor** tag.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
 // reactClass --
    return (
      <div>
      <Link to='https://react.semantic-ui.com/'>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-info">Button</button>
      </Link>
      </div>
    );
  // end--
```

Comment: "Uncaught Error: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>"

Comment: Whenever you try to show a Link on a page thats outside the BrowserRouter you will get that error.

This error message is essentially saying that any component that is not a child of our <Router> cannot contain any React Router related components.
You need to migrate your component hierarchy.

Comment: This is not openning a new tab neither overwrting the actual link showed at the address bar.

Comment: In this case, a classic <a href="https://react.semantic-ui.com/" target="_blank"> will work.So to solve what you are trying to achieve, the easiest way is to add a <a> over your <Button>.

Comment: Nesting `<a>` and `<button>` is invalid HTML. See [validation error](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdropbox.beausmith.com%2Fstatic-html%2Finvalid-button-anchor-markup.html)

Comment: Hi, Have you faced any errors while implementing the answer? if I'm not wrong can you please check this answer, on the ref of your comment? Thank you :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need jQuery nor React to do that. It's as simple as this:

```js
var ex = document.getElementById('ex');
ex.onclick = function(){
  console.log('clicked');
}

var bt = document.getElementById('bt');
bt.onclick = function(){
  ex.click();
}
```

```html
<button id="bt">Click</button>
<a id="ex">Triggerable link</a>
```

Of course, in React you can store the `ref` of the components, bind to the event and then trigger the event like this:

```
onClick(){
    this.ex.click();
}
render(){
    return (
        <div>
          <button id="bt" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} ref={(ref)=>{this.bt = ref}}>Click</button>
          <a id="ex" onClick={()=>console.log("clicked")} ref={(ref)=>{this.ex = ref}}>Triggerable link</a>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Edit**: If you just want a button that behaves like a link, you can use this, or any of the solutions listed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link):

```
onClick(){
    window.location.href="http://url.com";
}
render(){
    return (
        <button id="bt" onClick={this.onClick}>Click</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: can your ReactJS solution not have a separate link?  I just want a button that results in the same thing as a link click, without there being a link.

Comment: Done. May I ask why exactly do you need it to be a button?

Comment: I get "Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag" when using <button> and <a> tags in the example code under "Of course, in React you can..."

Comment: @DarylSpitzer my mistake, thanks for pointing it out. I wrapped the components in a `<div>`.

Comment: I would change one thing here. I would add a `{display: "none"}` style to the `<a>` tag in your `ref`example

Answer (score 4):

## 2021 Update :

```
<div
    style={{
      width: 15,
      height: 15,
      background: "blue",
      cursor: "pointer",
    }}
    onClick={() => {
      window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :)

`<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com"> <button id="bt" >Click</button> </a>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
  import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    const handleClick = (url)=>{
       const navigate = useNavigate(); 
       navigate(url);
     }
```

The ***useNavigate*** hook returns a function that lets you navigate to a specific link